# I can't find any other function that satisfies these conditions

Tags: functions

Let $f: \mathbb{N^*} \to \mathbb{N^*}$ be a bijective function.

Is there any other function besides $f(x) = x, x \in \mathbb{N^*}$ that satisfies the definition above?

Comment: What is $\mathbb{N}^*$?

Comment: $\mathbb{N^*}$ is $\mathbb{N} - \{0\}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what does $\mathbb {N^*}$ mean. I'll assume you mean $\mathbb {N}$.

Is $g:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ defined by:

$$g(x) = \begin{cases} 2 &x = 1 \\
                       1 & x = 2 \\
                     x & x > 2
\end{cases}$$

Answer your question?

Comment: This is correct but you forgot about the case when $x = 0$

Answer (score 1):

On a more general level, what the poster Marc Grec is inquiring here is whether given an arbitrary set $A$ there are other bijections from it to itself (these objects are called more elegantly permutations of $A$) apart from the obvious one, the identity mapping $\mathbf{1}_A$. In other words, one asks of the cardinality of the set $\Sigma(A)$ of all permutations of $A$, and finds the answer in the following:

> **Theorem**: If $A$ is finite, then $|\Sigma(A)|=|A|!$. If $A$ is infinite, then $|\Sigma(A)|=2^{|A|}$.

Therefore, if $A$ has at least $2$ elements $a, b$ than it will admit a nontrivial permutation (for instance, the one interchanging $a$ with $b$ and leaving all others fixed).